# shared_from_this() is called after object pointing by this is destroyed: C++ ASIO

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, smart-pointers

I am tryin to develop ASIO Application and have referred [Chat-Server](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.2/src/examples/cpp03/chat/chat_server.cpp)

When my `CServer Object` destructs it causes `CSerSessionsManager Object` to destruct- which holds `shared pointer` to all active chat sessions. It causes all active `CSerCession Objects` to destroy as well.

See the Definitions

```
class CServer {

    CServer(asio::io_service& io_service, const std::string serIdentity, std::string IP, const std::string port);
    ~CServer();
.....

private:

    mutable tcp::acceptor acceptor_; // only in the listener
    asio::io_service& io_;
    CSerSessionsManager mng_;

......

};


class CSerSessionsManager{
public:
    CSerSessionsManager();
    ~CSerSessionsManager();

    void addSession(sessionPtr session);
    void dropSession(sessionPtr session);

private:

    std::set<sessionPtr> sessions_; //Active Sessions : Online Info

};

class CSerSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CSerSession>{
    public:
        CSerSession(asio::io_service& io_service, CSerSessionsManager& mng, const std::string serverID,
            const std::string ip, const std::string port);
        ~CSerSession();

.......
    private:

        mutable tcp::socket socket_;   // client connection
        CSerSessionsManager& manager_;
......

    };
```

But since the `CSerSession Object` destroys it causes `read error` for active session and `read_handle()` is called.

```
void CSerSession::handle_read(const asio::error_code& error /*error*/, size_t bytes_transferred /*bytes_transferred*/)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        //do Something
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG_MSG("Read Error Detected : " << error.message());
        //Check If shared_from_this() is valid or not
        try
        {

            //if (error == asio::error::operation_aborted)
            manager_.dropSession(shared_from_this()); //Exception Here
        }
        catch (const std::bad_weak_ptr& e)
        {
            DEBUG_MSG(e.what());
            throw e;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The code throws exception at **Exception Here.**
On debugging it shows:

```
this    0x0044697c {socket_={...} manager_={sessions_={ size=??? } sessionPool_={ size=??? } } ip_=<Error reading characters of string.> ...}
std::enable_shared_from_this<channel::CSerSession>  {_Wptr={[deleter and allocator]={_Uses=??? _Weaks=??? } } }
socket_ {...}
manager_    {sessions_={ size=??? } sessionPool_={ size=??? } }
ip_ <Error reading characters of string.>
port_   <Error reading characters of string.>
parentServer_   <Error reading characters of string.>
servicedClientID_   <Error reading characters of string.>
serSessioID_    <Error reading characters of string.>
serSessionIdentifier_   <Error reading characters of string.>
privilege_  -274
serSessionIdentitySet_  true (238)
msg_    {received_=0x00446a77 "þîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþî... }
writeQueue_ { size=4277075694 }
```

I can see that `manager_.dropSession(shared_from_this());` is being called when debugger shows `std::enable_shared_from_this<channel::CSerSession>  {_Wptr={[deleter and allocator]={_Uses=??? _Weaks=??? }`.

It is being called after the destruction of `CSerSession object` as `read_error` is being set. Default behavior on error is to destroy the session and hence `manager_.dropSession(shared_from_this());` is mandatory there.

The problem is that the destruction of `this object` causing `read_error` which again tries to destroy the same object via `manager_.dropSession(shared_from_this());`

How do I resolve the error?

**EDIT:**
Summarizing the Issue:

Any error during chat session should set `read error` and `read_handle()` should be called which then destroys chat session via `manager_.dropSession(shared_from_this());`

But when my chat session `CSerSession Object` is going out of scope  i.e. destructor is called, it is also causing `read error` as it was active. So again `manager_.dropSession(shared_from_this());` is being called.

So basically `shared_from_this()` is being indirectly called from destructor.

Comment: I would recommend coming up with a small, self-contained compilable example that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you read from socket and set `CSerSession::handle_read` read handler, you should bind `shared_from_this()` instead of `this`.

For example, your `async_read()` should look similar to this:

```
socket_.async_read(boost::asio::buffer(...),
                   std::bind(&CSerSession::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                             std::placeholder::_1, 
                             std::placeholder::_2);
```

The problem you observe is caused by the nature of event queue. When you destroy `CSerSession` some events in the event queue may keep `this` pointer to object that was already destructed. Thats why developers recommend using `shared_ptr` and `shared_from_this()`. When you pass `shared_ptr` instead of `this` you keep object of interest alive.

**Response to your edit:**

You are saying that `manager_.dropSession(shared_from_this());` is being indirectly invoked from destructor. But how come object is being destructed, if `read_handle()` still keeps a reference it? Do you provide `read_handle()` with a `shared_from_this()` as I mentioned above?

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Not getting above mentioned error. But now `acceptor destruction` causing `Listen handle error`. So tried passing `shared_from_this()` in `async_accept()` but it is throwing `bad_weak_ptr` error. How to go about this?

Comment: @GauravK, probably `acceptor` is holding socket object as a member, so destroying it destructs socket, hence the error. About `bad_weak_ptr` error: are you using `weak_ptr`s yourself? Can you show backtrace of the place where this exception is thrown from?

Comment: @Guarav ask a new question please