# C++ ASIO: async_accept() handler throws exception when server destroys

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am developing a C++ ASIO based application. Referring to [Chat Server](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.2/src/examples/cpp03/chat/chat_server.cpp)

My Server Class:

```
class CServer  {

public:

    CServer(asio::io_service& io_service, const std::string serIdentity, std::string IP, const std::string port);
    ~CServer();

    void listen();
    void handle_accept(sessionPtr newSession, const asio::error_code& error);
private:

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_; // only in the listener
    asio::io_service& io_;
    CSerSessionsManager mng_;

};

void CServer::listen()
{
sessionPtr newSession = std::make_shared<channel::CSerSession>(io_, mng_, serIdentifier_, ip_, port_);

    acceptor_.async_accept(newSession->socket(), std::bind(&CServer::handle_accept, this, newSession,
                std::placeholders::_1));
} 

    void CServer::handle_accept(sessionPtr newSession, const asio::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        //Do Something
        listen();
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG_MSG("Listen_Error");
        //Returning from here throws Exception
    }
    
}
```

When my `CServer Object` destroys, after calling `~CServer()` **It sets  `Handle Accept` error** because an existing default listening session is active. And while returning from `handle_accept()` it throws exception.

`Unhandled exception at 0x74E8C42D in channel.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::system_error> > at memory location 0x023EF3EC.`

below is the call stack:

```
>   channel.exe!boost::throw_exception<std::system_error>(const std::system_error & e) Line 69  C++
    channel.exe!asio::detail::do_throw_error(const std::error_code & err) Line 32   C++
    channel.exe!asio::detail::throw_error(const std::error_code & err) Line 34  C++
    channel.exe!asio::io_service::run() Line 59 C++
    channel.exe!boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,asio::io_service>::operator()(asio::io_service * p) Line 49   C++
    channel.exe!boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<asio::io_service *> >::operator()<unsigned int,boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,asio::io_service>,boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<unsigned int> __formal, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,asio::io_service> & f, boost::_bi::list0 & a, long __formal) Line 244  C++
    channel.exe!boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned int,boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,asio::io_service>,boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<asio::io_service *> > >::operator()() Line 21   C++
    channel.exe!asio::detail::win_thread::func<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned int,boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,asio::io_service>,boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<asio::io_service *> > > >::run() Line 116    C++
    channel.exe!asio::detail::win_thread_function(void * arg) Line 109  C++
```

I had similar issue with `session class destruction` [Asked Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544162/shared-from-this-is-called-after-object-pointing-by-this-is-destroyed-c-asi/28544417?noredirect=1#comment45403696_28544417)

How do I resolve this and ensure clean exit when `~CServer()` is called.

Comment: Why are you destroying your `CServer` object if it's still listening for incoming connections?

Comment: There are multiple `CServer` , So when one goes out of scope `handle_accept()` error generates. This happens also if i call `acceptor_.close()` and while returning from `handle_accept` - an exception is thrown. How do I ensure clean destruction of `CServer Class`

Comment: generally, you ensure a `CServer`s object lifetime extends as long as it's performing work, such as listening for incoming connections. This is typically done by inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this`, several of the Asio examples use this concept.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest having a look at the various [HTTP Server Examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html) for Boost ASIO as they are more complete than the chat example.

One pattern that works for shutdown of a server object is to have a `handle_stop` method that closes the acceptor and shuts down the connections, e.g. the following from the single-threaded HTTP Server Example linked above:

```
void server::handle_stop()
{
  // The server is stopped by cancelling all outstanding asynchronous
  // operations. Once all operations have finished the io_service::run() call
  // will exit.
  acceptor_.close();
  connection_manager_.stop_all();
}
```

In the Boost example, this is called by a Ctrl-C handler:

```
  // Register to handle the signals that indicate when the server should exit.
  // It is safe to register for the same signal multiple times in a program,
  // provided all registration for the specified signal is made through Asio.
  signals_.add(SIGINT);
  signals_.add(SIGTERM);
#if defined(SIGQUIT)
  signals_.add(SIGQUIT);
#endif // defined(SIGQUIT)
  signals_.async_wait(boost::bind(&server::handle_stop, this));
```

But you might want to shut-down explicitly from a stop method, like:

```
void server::stop()
{
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&server::handle_stop, this));
}
```

If you need more advice on how to hook that in, we'll need to see the rest of your ASIO code.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still stuck at the same point, to understand the issue better I have simplified my application and asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564029/asio-chat-session-class-throws-exception-on-destruction-c-asio  Could you please have a look?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607788/destroying-server-instance-asio-c Can you please have a look @softwariness